# Get an element from an ID by.css() in protractor

Tags: unit-testing, protractor

Using protractor, I would like to get a canvas which is in div. For example like this:

```
<div id="myId">
 <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the canvas can not have an id for some reasons. 
Therefore, I would like to know if it was possible to do something like that with protractor:

```
let myCanvas = element(by.css('#myId > canvas'));
```

Comment: remove the `>`. `element(by.css('#myId canvas'));` should work

Comment: try this https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.id

Comment: @DublinDev this is not working for me

Comment: [It works for me](https://imgur.com/a/X2Qv6Hj). Actually upon refection your original locator should work as is.

Comment: Alright I have to investigate what I am doing later.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const myCanvas = $('#myId canvas');
```